# python regex if|else not working as advertised?

Tags: python, regex, if-statement, documentation

I'm trying to educate myself on how the `if|else` pattern matching works in python and so created the following test from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html). As near as I can tell it's not working per documentation but I've learned to assume I missed a critical step somewhere.

In this test case the third item **should** fail because it's missing its closing '>'.

```
In [1]: import re, sys
In [2]: regex = re.compile('(<)?(\w+@\w+(?:\.\w+)+)(?(1)>|$)')
In [3]: cases  = ['<user@host.com>', 'user@host.com', '<user@host.com', 'user@host.com>']

In [4]: [ re.search(regex, _) and ("match:", _) or ("fail:", _) for _ in cases ]
Out[4]:
[('match:', '<user@host.com>'),
 ('match:', 'user@host.com'),
 ('match:', '<user@host.com'),
 ('fail:', 'user@host.com>')]

In [5]: sys.version
Out[5]: '3.6.5 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Apr 26 2018, 08:42:37) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]'
```

Relevant:

> `(?(id/name)yes-pattern|no-pattern)`
>
> Will try to match with `yes-pattern`
>   if the group with given id or name exists, and with no-pattern if it
>   doesn’t. `no-pattern` is optional and can be omitted. For example,
>   `(<)?(\w+@\w+(?:\.\w+)+)(?(1)>|$)` is a poor email matching pattern,
>   which will match with '`<user@host.com>`' as well as '`user@host.com`',
>   but not with '`<user@host.com`' nor '`user@host.com>`'.

So my question is, what step did I miss? Tried on different python versions and hosts/os.

Comment: The problem isn't the `if|else`. The problem is that your regex needs an end-of-string anchor `$` or `\Z`.

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but you should really use `yes_case if condition else no_case` instead of `condition and yes_case or no_case`. It's less bug-prone, since it doesn't go to `no_case` when `yes_case` is falsy.

Comment: Yeah - just wanted a quick demo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `search`, asking whether the string *contains* a match for your regex, rather than asking whether it *is* a match. `<user@host.com` contains a match, specifically `user@host.com`.

Use [`fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) rather than `search`.

Comment: That was it.  Sigh. In an earlier iteration I'd tested `match` on a slightly different regex and didn't think to try it again with the original regex. Thanks!